# Dimension of $A^{ij}_k$ 3 index antisymmetric traceless tensor representation of SU(N)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, physics, tensors

I am trying to find the dimension (n° of components) of the antisymmetric traceless tensor $A^{ij}_k$ which is a representation in $SU(N)$. As it is antisymmetric in $ij$, we know that $A^{ij}_k = - A^{ji}_k$. My attempt is as follows:

1. $i$ can take $N$ elements
2. $j$ can take $N-1$ elements (because as it is antisymmetric, all elements (N in total) with $i=j$ are $0$)
3. In order to avoid linearly dependent terms, we divide by 2 and get $$\frac{1}{2}N(N-1)$$
4. $k$ can take $N$ elements, so we have in total $$\frac{1}{2}N^2(N-1)$$

However, the solution says we in fact get $$\frac{1}{2}N^2(N-1) - N$$
Where was my mistake?
It also says that $T^i_j$ antisymmetric in $i$ has $N^2-1$ dimensions. Why?

I appreciate your answers.

Comment: You didn't use the traceless condition. I can only assume traceless means something like $A^{ij}_i = 0$ for all $j$; assuming these $N$ linear equations are independent, so you lose $N$ degrees of freedom. $T^i_j$ cannot be "antisymmetric" in $i$ because $i$ is only one index. If you mean $i, j$ then $N^2 - 1$ is incorrect; but if you mean $T^i_j$ is traceless with no other condition then there are $N^2$ entries from which we lose one degree of freedom via $T^i_i = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Nicholas Todoroff.
My problem was with the definition of traceless. For tensors in $SU(N)$ of the form $A^{ij}_k$ it means that $A^{ij}_i = 0$. For a constant $j$, $1$ component of the $N$ $A^{ij}_i$'s is linearly dependent of the other $N-1$ components. That is $1$ component less. However, as $j$ runs to $N$ we in total have $N$ components less.